# converting seconds to dd:hh:mm:ss or Days Hours Mins Secs

Tags: javascript, angular9

I'm creating a custom pipe for converting seconds to either dd:hh:mm:ss or Days Hours Minutes Seconds by a boolean argument passed through pipe. Here is My current Code (same to be placed inside transfrom function of custom-pipe class):

```js
let d=h=m=s=0 ;
  let td, th,tm,ts ;
  function transform(value, wordFormat = false){
    h = Math.floor(value / 3600) ;
    temp = value % 3600 ;
    m = Math.floor( this.temp / 60) ;
    s = this.temp % 60 ;
    if (h > 24){
      d = Math.floor( this.h / 24) ;
      h = this.h % 24 ;
    }
    else{
      d = 0 ;
    }

    if (wordFormat){
      if (d){
        td = `${d} days` ;
        th = `${h} hours` ;
        return td + ' ' + th ;
      }
      else{
        if (h){
          th = `${h} hours` ;
          tm = `${m} mins` ;
          return th + ' ' + tm ;
        }
        else{
          if (m){
            tm = `${m} mins` ;
            return tm ;
          }
          else{
            ts = `${s} secs` ;
            return ts ;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    else{
      if (d){
        td = `0${d}`.slice(-2) ;
        th = `0${h}`.slice(-2) ;
        tm = `0${m}`.slice(-2) ;
        ts = `0${s}`.slice(-2) ;
        return `${td}:${th}:${tm}:${ts}` ;
      }
      else{
        if (h){
          th = `0${h}`.slice(-2) ;
          tm = `0${m}`.slice(-2) ;
          ts = `0${s}`.slice(-2) ;
          return `${th}:${tm}:${ts}` ;
        }
        else{
          tm = `0${m}`.slice(-2) ;
          ts = `0${s}`.slice(-2) ;
          return `${tm}:${ts}` ;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  
  document.write('word format: ' +transform(20000, true) + '<br>')
  document.write('digit format: ' + transform(20000)+ '<br>')
  document.write('Conversion is wrong(for decimal values): ' +transform(200.556456)+ '<br>')
```

I think my basic conversion of seconds is only holds good when it's in integer form, for decimal values it's providing wrong answer. How can I modify my function to work for both decimal and integer value of input. (As my data that will be provided in my project may/may not be in integer from) ;

Comment: You're not showing fractions of seconds anyway, so just `Math.round()` the value before using it to get rid of the decimals, I guess?

Comment: @chrisg I thought I needed to change my conversion process. By adding this `value = Math.round(value)` solved the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the above answers are good, though as found out by **Chris G** I just needed to round the seconds value which was messing the whole time string so `Math.round(value)` solves this issue without going towards a new approach.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
 transform(milliseconds: seconds, args?: any) { 
   var cd = 24 * 60 * 60 ,
            ch = 60 * 60 ,
            day = Math.floor(seconds / cd),
            hr = Math.floor((seconds - day * cd) / ch),
            min = Math.round((seconds - day * cd - hr * ch) / 60);
        if (min === 60) {
            hr++;
            min = 0;
        }
        if (hr === 24) {
            day++;
            min = 0;
        }
        var valStr = (day != 0) ? day + " day(s) " : "";
        valStr += (hr != 0) ? hr + " hr(s) " : "";
        valStr += (min != 0) ? min + " min(s) " : "";
        return valStr;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of the real world use or the format you will want to utilize in your app, but this may help simplify the whole procedure a lot.
consider it a Beta testing approach and solution.

```js
function transform( value, word ) {
    with( new Date( value * 1000) )
    var dd = getUTCDate() - 1,
        hh = getUTCHours(),
        mm = getUTCMinutes(),
        ss = getUTCSeconds(),
        ml = getUTCMilliseconds(),
    dg = toUTCString().match(/\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}/);

 return word ? 
        (dd ? dd + " days " : "") + 
        (hh ? hh + " hours ": "") + 
        (mm ? mm + " minutes ": "") + 
        (ss ? ss + " seconds ": "") + 
        (ml ? ml + " miliseconds " : "" )
        :
        (dd ? dd + ":" : "") + dg[0] + (ml ? "." + ml : "");
  };
  
console.log("digital: " + transform( 85520.522, 0 ) );
console.log("words: " + transform( 85520.522, 1 ) );
console.log(transform( 567.12147, 1 ) );
console.log(transform( 12540, 1 ) );
console.log(transform( 12560.000, 1 ) );
console.log(transform( 23000.122, 1 ) );
console.log("digital: " + transform( (24*8640+27000.51), 0 ) );
console.log("words: " + transform( (24*8640+27000.51), 1 ) );
```

p.s.: maximum days are limited to 30, once this is exceeded it will dump them as months.